# Authentication failed: Include valid openId scopes like profile, email

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, openid, social-auth-app-django

I am building an app with `Django` and `social-auth-app-django`.

I followed [this tutorial](https://developerking.medium.com/django-authentication-with-facebook-instagram-and-linkedin-2babe3f6482b).

I created an app on LinkedIn for Developers, got the client_id and secret_key. I also made sure that the product `Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect` is added to my app.

In `settings.py`, I added all the OAUTH2 parameters:

```py
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = '...'  # Client ID
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = '...'  # Client Secret
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE =  ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email',
                                               'formatted-name',
                                               'public-profile-url',
                                               'picture-url']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [
    ('id', 'id'),
    ('formattedName', 'name'),
    ('emailAddress', 'email_address'),
    ('pictureUrl', 'picture_url'),
    ('publicProfileUrl', 'profile_url'),
]
```

However, I kept getting `Authentication failed: Scope "r_basicprofile" is not authorized for your application`.

I changed `SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE`:

```py
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE =  ['openid']
```

Now I get `Authentication failed: Include valid openId scopes like profile, email.`

Based on the official [LinkedIn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext#validating-id-tokens), I also tried

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
```

But I got `Authentication failed: Scope "r_liteprofile" is not authorized for your application`. again.

Has anyone an example of a settings.py configuration that works?